# Retreiving a 3rd-party webpage with CURL/PHP - not entirely working

Tags: php, curl, networking

I am writing a tool that accesses a set of external website pages. Here is my test code to see if I can retrieve the page:

```
function get_data($url) {

    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    /* curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout); */
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;

}

$returned_content = get_data('http://www.imdb.com/');
echo $returned_content;
```

---

The thing is when I pass Google (for example) as the URL, I get the Google homepage in my browser (sans images for obvious reasons), but when I pass the site I want to see, `www.imdb.com`, I get nothing. Why is this, and what can I do about it?

Comment: There's no reason not to work with IMDB. Please check the status of curl_exec - use curl_error if curl_exec returned false

Comment: They might not accept the curl user agent. You can try changing or see if curl_error returns anything.

Comment: @Jaime wrong, libcurl has no default useragent, and imdb.com doesn't require one, you can easily verify this yourself by running `curl -v http://www.imdb.com -H "User-Agent: "`

Comment: as i've said so many times before, when debugging curl code, enable CURLOPT_VERBOSE. add `curl_setopt_array($ch,array(CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>1,CURLOPT_STDERR=>STDOUT));` and run it again

Comment: I checked curl_error() and it was empty!! So not creating a curl error then??

Comment: $data = curl_exec($ch) returns false, so there is an error, but curl_error($ch) is empty.... Why is this?